# Remmina analogous commands to win remote desktop

Tags: remmina

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm used to logging into a work computer from windows remote desktop connection. In that environment, I need the server name, the computer name and my user name/password to log in.

I found the Remmina tool for remote login from an Ubuntu machine here:

[Unable to connect to Remote Desktop ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592582/unable-to-connect-to-remote-desktop)

In Remmina, I can guess which fields need to be filled in, however, I do not know how to login to a specific machine from these fields.

What I would like to know:

if in windows remote desktop connection I need to fill the fields:
Use these RD Gateway Server Settings: Server name = XXXXXX with bypass RD Gateway server for local addresses
Computer= YYYYYY
User name= ZZZZZZ

What analogous fields need to be entered in Remmina?

Thanks!